# How to see variables from another class function in a PHP class?

Tags: php, class, functional-programming, global-variables

How do I see variables from another function in the same class?

Here is the problem i have:

```
class slike {
    public function __construct($dire) { 
        $this->dire=$dire;
    }

    function skupljanjeslika() {
        $slike = array();
        $handler = opendir($this->dire);
        while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $slike[] = $file;
            }
        }

        closedir($handler);

        return $slike; // **Array i want to use!**
    }

    function prikazradnomslike() {
        $slike; // Here is the array from first function, but I can't see it here
        $rezultat = count($slike)-1;
        $koliko=rand(0, $rezultat);
        $slika=$slike[$koliko];

        return $slika;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you try to do this :

```
$slike = $this->skupljanjeslika();
```

Or if you method skupljanjeslika is used before, try this :
In your class, add a var :

```
protected $slike;
```

In skupljanjeslika replace the return by this :

```
$this->slike = $slike;
```

And in prikazradnomslike, do this :

```
$slike = $this->slike;
```

To be more efficient, you can definitly do this :

```
class slike {
    protected $slike;
    public function __construct($dire) { 
        $this->dire=$dire;
    }

    function skupljanjeslika() {
        $slike = array();
        $handler = opendir($this->dire);
        while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $slike[] = $file;
            }
        }

        closedir($handler);

        $this->slike = $slike;
    }

    function prikazradnomslike() {
        $rezultat = count($this->slike)-1;
        $koliko=rand(0, $rezultat);
        $slika=$this->slike[$koliko];

        return $slika;
    }
}
```

Comment: You think in main scope? Or inside function?

Comment: For my 1st solution, it was like this : 
`function prikazradnomslike() {
        $slike = $this->skupljanjeslika();`

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to the class:

```
class slike 
{
    $protected $slike;

     public function __construct($dire) {
     ...
```

Access it like this:

```
$this->slike;
```

Comment: Just to add it before construct, like you did it?

Comment: Yes, before the construct function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variable as a class variable, i suggest to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) to see how to declare class variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class slike {
  ...
  function prikazradnomslike()
  {
    $slike = $this->skupljanjeslika();
    return $slike[ array_rand($slike, 1) ];
  }
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/return and http://docs.php.net/array_rand

Comment: Thanks you gave me another great solution:     function prikazradnomslike()
{
    $slike = $this->skupljanjeslika();
 shuffle($slike);
 $slika=$slike[0];
 return $slika;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can either call `skupljanjeslika()` from where you want your return value like this: `$slike = $this->skupljanjeslika();` or you can pass in the array as a parameter if you want to call it from somewhere else:

```
function prikazradnomslike($slike)
{
    $rezultat = count($slike)-1;
    $koliko=rand(0, $rezultat);
    $slika=$slike[$koliko];
    return $slika;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a private property $slike in your class, set it in your slike::skuplanjeslika() and use it in your slike::prikazrandomslike(). Another option is to pass $slike as an argument to slike::prikazrandomslike:

```
class slike 
{
    public function __construct($dire)
    { 
        $this->dire=$dire;
    }

    function skupljanjeslika()
    {
        $slike = array();
        $handler = opendir($this->dire);
        while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $slike[] = $file;
        }
        }
        closedir($handler);
        return $slike; // **Array i want to use!**
    }
    function prikazradnomslike($slike)
    {
        $rezultat = count($slike)-1;
        $koliko=rand(0, $rezultat);
        $slika=$slike[$koliko];
        return $slika;
    }
}

$photos = new slike('mydir');
$photos->prikazrandomslike($photos->skuplanjeslika());
```

Comment: Hvala majstore, svaka cast, imas li neki email? Txanks this works great ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having has to do with "*scope*" ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php ). A variable is not accessible outside of the function in which it was originally declared.

If you want access to a variable anywhere within your script there are a number of ways to accomplish this. You can use global variables (not recommended in most cases) or declare them as part of a class (these can be `static` or not - more on that farther down the post).

A variable declared inside of a class will look something like this:

```
class myClass {
    public $var1;
    protected $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function foo() {
        return $this->var1;
    }
}
```

Make a note of `public`, `private` and `protected`, as these are very important keywords.

A private variable within a class is only accessible within that class - **it will not be inherited by any children, nor can it be accessed directly by an instance of the object (i.e. `$myClassObj->var1`)**

A protected variable will be inherited by child classes, but has the same access restrictions when using instances of the object.

A public variable is accessible directly and will be inherited.

In order to access any of these variables within the class, simply refer to it using the `$this` variable.

**E.G.:**

```
$this->$var1;
```

Now, if you declare a variable as `static` it will be available in memory at all times and accessible via the scope resolution operator (`::`). **HOWEVER** private and protected variables will not be directly accessible (same rules apply as before).

```
myClass::$var1 = 4; // this works fine, and sets $var1 to 4 across ALL instances of myClass
myClass::$var2 = 3; // this WILL NOT WORK - protected variable.
```

If you need to access a static variable within the class you must refer to it using the scope resolution operator and the keyword `self`.

```
class myClass {
    public static $var1;

    function bar() {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}
```